# How is props.children added inside opening and closing tags in React JS with children="xyz" attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

This is how I understand `props.children` in React:

```js
class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return ( <
      button > {
        this.props.children
      }
      " 12345" <
      /button>
    );
  }
}

function Toolbar(props) {
  return ( <
    ThemedButton onClick = {
      props.changeTheme
    } >
    Change Theme <
    /ThemedButton>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render( < Toolbar / > , document.getElementById('root'));
//this will generate <button>Change Theme 12345</button>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

So basically any child node(s) of `ThemedButton` will be put in place of `props.children`. This makes sense, but what doesn't make sense is if I omit `props.children` and instead just pass `{...props}` as attribute or use `children` attribute as property on the button tag, it still inserts the child node(s).  Following is the example:

```js
class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return ( 
    <button {...this.props}  ></button>  //child nodes are added automatically     
    );
  }
}

class ThemedButton2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return ( 
    <button children="XYZ"  ></button>
    );
  }
}


function Toolbar(props) {
  return ( 
  <React.Fragment>
    <
    ThemedButton onClick = {
      props.changeTheme
    } >
    Change Theme <
    /ThemedButton>
    <ThemedButton2> Change theme2 </ThemedButton2>
  </React.Fragment>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render( < Toolbar / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

As you can see `{...props}` on `button` seemingly brings actual child nodes of `ThemedButton>` as children property. In `ThemedButton2` I manually provided `children="xyz"`, which automatically inserts xyz as child nodes of `button`.

Why is this happening? Where does react explain this in it's official documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking that isn't covered [in the docs here](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children). Except perhaps for the part where you seem surprised that passing a `children` prop to a JSX `<button>` (which it would be more normal to put inside the opening and closing tags, which indeed is just synactic sugar for using the `children` prop) renders that content as the actual child nodes of the button. To which my only real response is "what else would you expect `<button>XYZ</button>` to render"?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I would expect it to render `<button> Change theme2 </button>`, reason being, props can be passed only to React components not pure html elements(`button`), e.g. here https://jsfiddle.net/rc8gwqzj/ `props.children` is not overridden by `children` attribute. I also don't know what to expect for `<button children="XYZ">123</button>`, should 123 text node be removed and replaced with children attribute's value?

Comment: in your fiddle, `this.props.children` inside is obviously "Change Theme" because `ThemedButton` because this is whay you're passing in. But you don't use it in the rendered output of that component, and in fact render an HTML `button`(or rather a JSX representation of one) with children "Not_change_theme". Those children are therefore what React will render as the actual children of the HTML button.

Comment: Your statement "props can be passed only to React components not pure html elements" is obviouisly not true. Both HTML children and HTMl attributes are passed as JSX props - although it's much more common to pass the `children` prop in JSX between the opening and closing tabs rather than using an explicit `children` prop. But your example in the fiddle shows that the `children` prop works too.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I am not aware of any way to pass props to pure html elements and it doesn't even make sense to me. You mentioned _Both HTML children and HTMl attributes are passed as JSX props_ Then in my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rc8gwqzj/ why doesn't on click the console log `testprop` as `button`'s prop? I don't think we have `button.props` at all.

Comment: your `this.props` that you are logging are the props passed to *the ThemedButton component*. Nowhere do you log the props passed to the plain `<button>` element - and of course you can't from outside get "inside" that component/element to log its props. But you can see clearly the props you do pass it inside the `render` of `ThemedButton`.

Comment: what do you think `onClick` is in `<button onClick={() => {console.log("click");}} />` is if not a prop? Note that this is not a plain HTML button, it's a React element, it just gets rendered as an HTML button by React itself.

Comment: Ok, makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at type definitions it should be quite clear:
`<button>` is of type

```
React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>;
```

React.DetailedHTMLProps is defined as:

```
type DetailedHTMLProps<E extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T> = ClassAttributes<T> & E;
```

so it extends HTMLAttributes, which is defined as:

```
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
...
}
```

and extends DOMAttributes, which is defined (finally) as:

```
interface DOMAttributes<T> {
            children?: ReactNode | undefined;
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML?: {
                __html: string;
            } | undefined;
    
            // Clipboard Events
            onCopy?: ClipboardEventHandler<T> | undefined;
            onCopyCapture?: ClipboardEventHandler<T> | undefined;
            onCut?: ClipboardEventHandler<T> | undefined;
            onCutCapture?: ClipboardEventHandler<T> | undefined;
            onPaste?: ClipboardEventHandler<T> | undefined;
            onPasteCapture?: ClipboardEventHandler<T> | undefined;
...
}
```

So, in the end, children is actually a valid prop of button, and if you overwrite it by stating:

```
<button children="TEST" />
```

It will actually render that children property.
In React docs they talk about this here: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common saying that:

> All built-in browser components, such as `<div />`, support some common props and events.

and those props are to be found here: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#common-props

and children is one of them:

> children: A React node (an element, a string, a number, a portal, an empty node like null, undefined and booleans, or an array of other React nodes). Specifies the content inside the component. When you use JSX, you will usually specify the children prop implicitly by nesting tags like .